# HTTPS returns plain text including headers

Tags: php, ssl, curl, nginx, https

During setting up for our production environment we encounter a wierd error, when trying to curl through our server, it returns a plain text representation of the response including the http headers this request is over ssl.

```
Date: Fri, 19 Jun 2015 02:15:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 70619
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 05:30:30 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "55825776-113db"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
and so on...
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to false in your [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) like so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

> CURLOPT_HEADER - TRUE to include the header in the output. ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php))

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this bug, it turns out I was setting CURLOPT_HEADER instead of CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER